# php variable not displaying correctly

Tags: php

Im trying to build a feeds application in php in which im using a simple table with 2 columns..one for name and one for the respective feeds...my feed is appearing properly but there is some problem with the name heres the code...

```
<?php
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, feed, feeddate FROM feeds ORDER BY feeddate DESC LIMIT     20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$name = $row["name"];
$uid = $row["userid"];
$ufeed = $row["feed"];
$feeddate = $row["feeddate"];


 $feeds .= '
        <table width="90%" align="center" cellpadding="4"    bgcolor="#A6D2FF">
    <tr>
      <td width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a  href="http://www.project360.in/emp_profile.php?id=' . $uid . '">' . $name . '</a><br />
      </td>
      <td width="93%" bgcolor="#D9ECFF"> <span style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold;   color:#A6A6A6;">' . $feeddate . '</span><br />
      ' . $ufeed . '</td>
    </tr>
  </table>';

}?>
<?php print "$feeds"; ?>
```

here the $name thing is simply not displaying as a link!please help..

Comment: I'm confused, you said 2 columns, I count 4, also, why would $name appear as a link? It's a name! And finally, what DO you see if not the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting only three columns:

```
SELECT id, feed, feeddate
```

"name" is not among them, so it will be always empty.

Answer (score 0):

`$row["name"]` is not set, because you did not include the *name* column in the select expression of the database query. Consequently, the statement

```
$name = $row["name"];
```

sets `$name` to `null`. The same holds for `$uid` and `$row["userid"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query should be

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name, id, feed, feeddate FROM feeds ORDER BY feeddate DESC LIMIT 20");`

Also, you have `$uid = $row["userid"];`. I believe it should be `$uid = $row["id"];` as you have `id` in sql query. You have to change either of them.

If you have `id` use above query, else use below query.

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name, userid, feed, feeddate FROM feeds ORDER BY feeddate DESC LIMIT 20");`

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting 3 columns `id,feed,feed date`.But you are printing `name,id,feed,feed date`. Please select name column also. It will display proper output.